# Xamarin.Forms Label inside grid row has it's text cut off

Tags: android, xamarin, grid, xamarin.forms, label

Xamarin.Forms label that is positioned in a fixed size grid row has it's text cut off, or rather, it shows too much text and the lowest line gets shown only by half due to fixed height of the grid row. The grid row height has to stay fixed.

```
gridInner.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1.8, GridUnitType.Star) });
gridInner.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(7.5, GridUnitType.Star) });
gridInner.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = new GridLength(1.7, GridUnitType.Star) });

var descLabel = new Label()
{
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Fill,
    FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)),
    FontAttributes = FontAttributes.None,
    TextColor = Color.Black,
    LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.WordWrap,
    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Start
};
descLabel.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, "Offer.Description");
gridInner.Children.Add(descLabel, 0, 1);
```

[image: Text cut off on Android 5.1(Lollipop)]

It seems to me that the label's height is larger than grid row's, or the text line height is calculated wrong. 
I've tried everything i could think of, for example:

```
<style name="App_TextViewStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView">
   <item name="android:baselineAligned">false</item>
   <item name="android:includeFontPadding">false</item>
   <item name="android:padding">1dp</item>
</style>
```

Could anyone more experienced in XF shed some light on me?

Comment: if the grid's height must be in fixed size, then the only thing I can think of is to reduce the fontsize of your label.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options as I see it -

1. Shrink the font size of the label
2. Don't use a fixed sized grid row. Use either `Auto` or `*`
3. Wrap your label in a `ScrollView` so that if it is cut off, the user can scroll within it to see the content.

Comment: the grid has to have fixed size unfortunately, i can't help this as it is in the specifications. I think i will have to write a custom renderer where i measure lineheight and divide the grid height with it, then set the maxlines property of textview to this value. I will come back here when i test it out

Comment: Did you find a good solution to this?  I am having a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

Keep "large text" in mind. 20% of all users change the default font size of the phone to be larger. You should test how that works.
You might need to set a max text size for this.
Otherwise the device will auto scale with the phone's settings.